# Is a Flask application running under a production server still a Flask application?

Tags: apache, flask, server

According to [Flask's documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/):

> You can use the builtin server during development, but you should use
>   a full deployment option for production applications.

Assume I am using [mod_wsgi](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/).

Is Flask still running "under the hood" with Apache delegating to it or is Flask "gone"? According to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20862119/1830334), one of Flask's obvious limitations is that it is single-threaded. If Apache is just delegating to Flask, wouldn't we run into the same issues? And if not, what is Flask for at all? What makes it a "Flask application"? In other words, is a production Flask application running under an Apache server really a Flask application and if so, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flask is not the development server, it's a framework for handling the request/response cycle of a web application.  (The dev server isn't even part of Flask, it's part of Werkzeug.)

A deployed project typically consists of a web server (Apache, Nginx, etc.), an application server (mod_wsgi, uwsgi, gunicorn, etc.), and a WSGI application (Flask in this case).

The development server just makes it easy to run your app when you don't have a real application server set up.  In your case, mod_wsgi takes the place of the development server, both of which run the Flask application.